# Python: Percent of Applications/Any record to their User Analysis

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, analysis

Good afternoon all, i have a dataframe below.

```
UserId  Application
    1       apple
    1       orange
    1       apple
    1       pear
    2       apple
    2       orange
    2       pear
    2       grapefruit
    3       apple
    3       grapefruit
    3       apple
    1       apple
```

I am trying to create a list that counts every unique application to the percent of UserIDs that have them. As an example of the output the table is below

```
Application    Percentage
apple              100
orange             66
pear               66 
grapefruit         66
```

This output is telling me that for every user, apple appears 100 percent of the time orange appears 66 percent of the time. etc etc but somehow i cannot get this to work.

My code below works but produces 3.0 as a value.

```
dfsearch['Percentage'] = (len(dfsearch.Application.value_counts())/len(dfsearch.UserID.value_counts()))
dfsearch
```

this is probably incorrect because its not a list, but that is why i need help :)

Answer (score 3):

You can start with dropping duplicate records with `drop_duplicates`, then call `value_counts`, divide by the number of unique users and multiply by 100:

```
x = df.drop_duplicates()['Application'].value_counts() / len(df['UserId'].unique()) * 100
x
```

Output:

```
apple         100.000000
pear           66.666667
grapefruit     66.666667
orange         66.666667
Name: Application, dtype: float64
```

And then convert it to DataFrame:

```
x.astype(int).to_frame('Percentage').rename_axis('Application').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Application  Percentage
0       apple         100
1        pear          66
2  grapefruit          66
3      orange          66
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby()` + `nunique()`:

```
dfsearch.groupby("Application").UserID.nunique()/dfsearch.UserID.nunique()
#Application
#apple         1.000000
#grapefruit    0.666667
#orange        0.666667
#pear          0.666667
#Name: UserId, dtype: float64
```